# How to combined the two mysql queries into one join one?

Tags: mysql

I have this dataset and in the status column, it will return the status of "passed", "failed", or "error". I want to use mysql query to find out how many are -"passed", and how many are "failed". I have two queries that can query the result separately:

(1)

```
 "select max(build),count(status) as "failed"
    from bioraddash.fullsuite
    where build = 2980 and status = "failed";"
```

(2)

```
 "select max(build),count(status) as "passed"
    from bioraddash.fullsuite
    where build = 2980 and status = "passed";"
```

those queries will return what I want in differnt queries.
my question is: how do I combined them so I can get both result in one query and get the result like below:

```
Maxbuild  passed failed
2980      2      0
```

Thanks,

I have no experience on how to combined them, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

`status="passed"` is a true (1) or false (0) expression. Summing them up is equivalent to a count of the expression.

```
select max(build),sum(status="passed") as "passed", sum(status="failed") as "failed"
    from bioraddash.fullsuite
    where build = 2980
```